# Как передать переменную в static django

Tags: django

Как передать переменную i из цикла в static? Помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос.

```
{% block content %}
    {% for i in dirs %}
        <img src="{% static 'image/{{ i }}/1.jpg'%}" alt="" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: А чего вы этим хотите добиться?

Comment: @Daniil1703 видимо, вывод соответствующих изображений

Comment: Можно фильтр какой-то написать, в принципе

Comment: У меня есть имена папок(dirs) и я пытаюсь вывести имена этих папок, но если i добавить к alt(alt="{{ i }}"), то все работает, а  если добавлять к src(src="{% static 'image/{{ i }}/1.jpg'%}"), то на выходе получается вот это <img src="/static/image/%7B%7Bi%7D%7D/1.jpg" alt="">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}image/{{ i }}/1.jpg" alt="" />
```

Но статика не просто так названа статикой, не желательно так делать.

Comment: Спасибо большое! А как правильно тогда сделать подскажите?

Comment: Если теги в шаблоне формируются **динамически** - это признак того, что вместо **статических** ресурсов в этих тегах стоит использовать media-данные. Вероятно, нужно завести в БД модель для этих данных.

Comment: Действительно. Я совсем забыл про это, спасибо за ответы!